# React load image from folder cause auto reload app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, express, frontend

This is the my project folder structure

- **backend**

  - index.ts
- **frontend**(react)

  - **assets**

    - logo.png
  - index.jsx
  - index.html
- **node_modules**
- **uploads**

  - myimage1.png
  - myimage2.png
  - myimage3.png
  - myimage4.png
  - myimage5.png
- **default-image.png**

**index.jsx**

```
data = [
 {msg:'firstimage',name:'myimage1'},
 {msg:'secondimage',name:'myimage2'},
 {msg:'thirdimage',name:'myimage3'},
 {msg:'fourthimage',name:'myimage4'},
 {msg:'fifthimage',name:'myimage5'},
]

<div>
 data.map((item) => (
 let img_path = '';
  try{
               img_path = require(`../uploads/${item.name}.png`)                             
  }
  catch(err){
               img_path = require(`../default-image.png`)                             
 
  }
   <img
    alt={item.msg}
    src={img_path}
  />
 )
<div>
```

Above code work fine but whenever new image is uploaded to `uploads` folder it cause the react app to restart and break the app.

Comment: inspect element and check the path of image

Answer (score 0):

Move `uploads` folder to inside `assets` folder

Comment: here images in ```uploads``` folder is not fixed. Through the frontend User can add or remove images from the ```upload``` folder. 
Is it possible to upload/remove image directly to/from  ```assets``` folder ?

Comment: You need to handle it in backend.